# Used to vs would structural difference

Tags: grammar, infinitives, will-would, used-to

I have a doubt on the following question.

> 1) I ______________ want to be a practising doctor but now I'm more interested in research.
>
> Options:
>   A. was used to
>   B. used to
>   c. would

I was going with **would** but the correct answer is **used to**.

> Tips:
>   **1.We use used to + infinitive to talk about permanent situations that are usually no longer true**.
>
> **2. We do not use used to if we want to talk about how long the situation lasted**.
>
> Reference: Cambridge Grammar for IELTS

Now although I read this two tips, but still this answer is not clear to me. Is this question related to any permanent situation?

I still don't understand the reason behind the choice *used to*, rather than *would*.

Comment: You may want to check this video: https://www.engvid.com/english-grammar-would-in-the-past/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Would** and **used to** have very similar meaning but the main difference is that **used to** can be used to talk about past **states** while **would** only applies to past habits.

> **Want to be a practising doctor** is a state of mind not a habit/repeated actions.

For more information, check [this explanation](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode69/languagepoint.shtml) at the BBC's Learning English website.